# Is there a way to return databases to pool, after testwhileidle fails when using Tomcat connection pool?

Tags: database, tomcat, connection, jndi, pool

I'm currently working with tomcat connection pool DataSource and its valiodation options. I have several databases which i want to validate with the testWhileIdle property and a custom validator. Everything works fine but because of the testWhileIdle property, a database is dropped from the pool, when the connection fails. I can see in the logs that that database is not tested anymore even when its back up. My question is now if there is a way to bring then back, when for example the database is back up?

Thanks Guys.

Wrote a custom validator for the tomcat connection pool datasources with uses the validation querys to validate the connection of each database.